# Why do some foreign key violations cause a RuntimeExceptions and others just show a warning?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

In the following example I am using an `SQLitenOpenHelper`. I now with Room it's not timely anymore, but nevertheless I want to understand what is going on.

When I try to insert a row into a child table that has a foreign key reference that does not have a corresponding row in the parent table, Logcat shows an error but I get no runtime crash.

When I try to delete a column from the parent table that is referenced in a row in the child table, and have not defined the `ON DELETE` behavior, I get a runtime exception with "code 767.

Why do some foreign key constraints in Android SQLite cause a crash and others don't?

Comment: Most likely something is catching the error.  But without code we can't tell.

Comment: But my code is not catching any exceptions, it just seems to be the SQLite default